# How to connect to SQL Server from Red Hat 6.4 via Node.js

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js, authentication, redhat

Currently I am developing the Node.js web app on my local Mint linux machine, and connect to a local SQL Server 2008 (express) via SQL Server Authentication by using this node module [mssql](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mssql). Everything is fine now.

But now I need to deploy the app to a Red Hat 6.4 (64bit) machine and SQL Server 2008 R2. I was given a Windows Authentication way to access the SQL Server. I can use the Windows Authentication via the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to see the database and create tables. But how I can connect the app on Red Hat to the SQL server via Node.js?

I have installed this [MS ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36437) on the Red Hat server. What should the next move be? or best practise.

Answer (score 0):

I just successfully connected to the SQL Server from Ubuntu 14.04.

I use FreeTDS as the driver, and unxiODBC as the driver manager, node odbc as the Node.js module to connect.

More information can see [this link](http://flopalm.com/connect-to-ms-sql-server-via-windows-authentication-from-linux/).

But I need to do more research, wondering if I can use the node module mssql to connect. mssql uses tds or tedious as drivers.